# Nginx with special char in url returns a 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404, special-characters

I use nginx and php-fpm to host my wordpress website, i have a big problem with the slugs:

When i write with the media plugin a picture name with some french spécial characters nginx returns me a 404.

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Collier-éléphant-bois-os-argent-300x300.jpg
-> returns a 404

and

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Collier-%C3%A9l%C3%A9phant-bois-os-argent-350x350.jpg
-> returns a 404

The file is hosted on /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/ directory and named Collier-éléphant-bois-os-argent-300x300.jpg

Can you help me to fix it?

nginx conf:

```
 server {

charset UTF-8;

## Your website name goes here.
server_name example.com www.example.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

## Your only path reference.
root /var/www/example.com/www/htdocs/;
index index.php index.html;

server_name_in_redirect off;
port_in_redirect off;

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
access_log        off;
expires           30d;
}

# rewrite rules
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
}
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Cordialy,

Comment: How can we help you as you neither show any nginx configuration nor do you mention which software runs on the PHP side. You should also say if the 404 is generated from nginx or from your PHP application.

Comment: The 404 is generated from nginx.

Comment: I think you should rather use `try_files` in your `/` location. Have a look at the nginx wiki page for wordpress [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress).

Comment: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; and if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
} also do the same work .. nginx conf not need to be post there. I know what i am doing. I just don't know,why my static files are not distribued when they contain special characters.

Comment: I have also read the Wordpress wiki and issuing the same error and i have take a deep search using google before posting it there .

Answer (score 0):

Probably your server is with misconfigured locale settings and can't correctly translate non ASCII characters to filenames.

You need to ensure that file system use utf8 for file names and also that uploaded files are with correctly encoded file names.